# Is this function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow{S^{n}}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus{\{0\}}\rightarrow{S^{n}}$ and $g: S^{n}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\setminus{\{0\}}$ be functions given by $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{x}{||x||}$ and $g(x)=x$, where $|| x ||$ is the module of x.

Are $ f $ and $ g $ continuous functions?

Does anyone have any suggestions to demonstrate the continuity of f and g?

Comment: The first one is not defined on the origin.

Comment: Did you try the second one? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Let $U\subseteq{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}$ be a open subset. Let us see that $ g^ {- 1} (U) = U$ is an open subset of $ S^{n} $. Let $ x \in g ^ {- 1} (U) $ be. Then exist $r>0$ such that $B(g(x),r)\subseteq{U}$. Is that enough?

Comment: f is a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Seriously? What are those functions?

Comment: @Darkmaster note $\lVert x \rVert$ is continuous (trivially so, by definition of a metric), compose with $1/x$ which is continuous whenever $x \neq 0$, and multiply by $x$. Each of these actions is continuous. $g$ being continuous is trivial - it is simply an inclusion map, which is the identity map when we restrict the codomain

Answer (score 3):

The continuity of $g$ is straight forward. The map $g$ is simply the inclusion map. Fix $x_0 \in S^n$, $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $\delta = \varepsilon$. Then
$$\|x - x_0\| < \delta \implies \|g(x) - g(x_0)\| = \|x - x_0\| < \delta = \varepsilon.$$
The continuity of $f$ is less straight forward. Fix $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$, and $\varepsilon > 0$. We wish to find a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\|x - x_0\| < \delta \implies \|f(x) - f(x_0)\| = \left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\| < \varepsilon.$$
In order to figure out such a $\delta$, it is typically prudent to start with the $\|f(x) - f(x_0)\| < \varepsilon$, and work backwards.

**Remember:** we are always allowed to substitute $\|f(x) - f(x_0)\|$ for something larger. If we can make this larger quantity smaller than $\varepsilon$, then $\|f(x) - f(x_0)\|$ will be smaller than $\varepsilon$ too.

We have
\begin{align*}
\|f(x) - f(x_0)\| &= \left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{x_0}{\|x_0\|}\right\| \\
&= \left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{x}{\|x_0\|} + \frac{x}{\|x_0\|} - \frac{x_0}{\|x_0\|}\right\| \\
&\le \left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{x}{\|x_0\|}\right\| + \left\|\frac{x}{\|x_0\|} - \frac{x_0}{\|x_0\|}\right\| \\
&\le \left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{x}{\|x_0\|}\right\| + \left\|\frac{x}{\|x_0\|} - \frac{x_0}{\|x_0\|}\right\| \\
&= \left|\frac{1}{\|x\|} - \frac{1}{\|x_0\|}\right|\|x\| + \frac{1}{\|x_0\|}\|x - x_0\|.
\end{align*}
In order to make this less than $\varepsilon$, we can make each of the terms in the sum less than $\varepsilon / 2$. The right term is easy; if we force $\delta \le \frac{\varepsilon \|x_0\|}{2}$, then
$$\|x - x_0\| < \delta \implies \|x - x_0\| < \frac{\varepsilon \|x_0\|}{2} \implies \frac{1}{\|x_0\|} \|x - x_0\| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
as needed.

The other term is more tricky for a couple of reasons. Firstly, the $\|x\|$ term is not constant; we can't just treat it the same way we did with the $\|x_0\|$ term. It's not even bounded, meaning that $\|x\|$ could be arbitrarily large! That is, unless we limit $\delta$. If we force, say $\delta \le \frac{\|x_0\|}{2}$, then we can say for sure that
$$\|x - x_0\| < \delta \implies \|x - x_0\| < \frac{\|x_0\|}{2} \implies \|x\| \le \|x - x_0\| + \|x_0\| < \frac{3\|x_0\|}{2}.$$
Note that I could have replaced $\frac{\|x_0\|}{2}$ with any positive number (e.g. $1$). I've chosen $\frac{\|x_0\|}{2}$ specifically because I know I'll want (very soon) for $x$ to be bounded away from $0$. The closer to $0$ that $x$ becomes, the larger $\frac{1}{\|x\|}$ becomes, and the larger $\left|\frac{1}{\|x\|} - \frac{1}{\|x_0\|}\right|$ becomes. By bounding $\delta$ by $\frac{\|x_0\|}{2}$, I ensure that

\begin{align*}
\|x - x_0\| < \delta &\implies \|x_0\| - \|x\| \le \|x - x_0\| < \frac{\|x_0\|}{2} \\
&\implies \|x\| > \|x_0\| - \frac{\|x_0\|}{2} = \frac{\|x_0\|}{2} \\
&\implies \frac{1}{\|x\|} < \frac{2}{\|x_0\|}.
\end{align*}

Under this assumption of $\delta \le \frac{\|x_0\|}{2}$, note that
$$\left|\frac{1}{\|x\|} - \frac{1}{\|x_0\|}\right| = \frac{1}{\|x\| \cdot \|x_0\|} \cdot \Big|\|x\| - \|x_0\|\Big| \le \frac{2}{\|x_0\|^2}\|x - x_0\|.$$
From the working above, we further have, under this same assumption
$$\left|\frac{1}{\|x\|} - \frac{1}{\|x_0\|}\right| \|x\| \le \frac{2}{\|x_0\|^2}\|x - x_0\| \cdot \frac{3\|x_0\|}{2} = \frac{3}{\|x_0\|}\|x - x_0\|.$$
We can make this less than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ by making $\delta \le \frac{\varepsilon\|x_0\|}{6}$.

So, in summary, in order for our $\delta$ to work, it must be less than or equal to $\frac{\|x_0\|}{2}$, $\frac{\varepsilon\|x_0\|}{6}$, and $\frac{\varepsilon\|x_0\|}{2}$. Note that the latter is redundant, so our choice for $\delta$ is (at long last)
$$\delta = \min \left\{\frac{\|x_0\|}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon\|x_0\|}{6}\right\}.$$

**This is not the proof.** To write out the proof, you now have to write all of the above out in a sensible order. You start by assuming that $\|x - x_0\| < \delta$, and you must conclude (using the above working) that $\|f(x) - f(x_0)\| < \varepsilon$. I'm going to leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

I will do the argument for $g: S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ where $g(x) = x$. This is easily done by the definition of continuity. (Note that we take the topologies on $S^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ to be the subspace topologies in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.) Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$. Then $U= B\cap \left(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\right)$ for some open $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Therefore, \begin{align*}g^{-1}(U) &= \left\{x\in S^n: g(x)\in U\right\} \\&= \left\{x\in S^n: x\in B\cap \left(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\right)\right\} \\&= S^n\cap \left[B\cap \left(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\right)\right].\end{align*}
Note that $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (for example, it is the complement of the closed set $\{0\}$; singletons are closed in Hausdorff spaces, which $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is in its standard topology). Therefore, $B\cap \left(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\right)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (finite intersection of opens sets is open). Thus, by definition of the topology on $S^n$, the set $S^n\cap \left[B\cap \left(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\right)\right]$ is open in $S^n$. We conclude that $g$ is continuous.

It is similar to show that $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow S^n$ given by $f(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is continuous. Here is the outline of the proof. Let $U$ be open in $S^n$. Then $U= B\cap S^n$ for some open $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. To prove that $f$ is continuous, you need to show that
$$f^{-1}(U) = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}: \frac{x}{\|x\|}\in B\cap S^n\right\}$$ is open in the topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$. That is, you want to show that $f^{-1}(U) = B^{\prime} \cap \left(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}\right)$ for some open $B^{\prime}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. If you draw the picture out in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is fairly easy to see why $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. In general, you just need to work though the definitions, and is slightly more tedious. By the way, since the collection of open balls $\left\{B_{\epsilon}(x): x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1},\,\epsilon>0\right\}$ is a basis for the topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, it suffices to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for all balls $B_{\epsilon}(x)$.